# imprimir resultado PHP em vários arquivos TXT

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo PHP que faz uma busca no Banco de dados e gera todas as URLs, armazenadas no banco de dados em um único arquivo.

```
www.url1.com
www.url2.com
Etc...
```

*(por linha)*

Gostaria de **imprimir** esse resultado, do php, em **vários arquivos TXT** com no máximo 18 mil linhas por arquivo.

```
Ex: arquivo1.txt arquivo2.txt Etc...
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Acho que o que você quer é isto: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: Se alguma resposta lhe serviu leia esse post https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Supondo MySQLi**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$query = "SELECT nome_coluna FROM nome_tabela";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$k=1;
$i=1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $res = $row["nome_coluna"]."\n";
    file_put_contents("arquivo".$i.".txt", $res, FILE_APPEND);
    //nos multiplos de 18000 muda o nome do arquivo acima
    if (($k%18000)==0){
        $i=$i+1;
    }

    $k=$k+1;
}
```

> [put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) - escreve uma string em um arquivo, caso este arquivo ainda não exista ele cria o arquivo.
>
> `FILE_APPEND` - acrescenta os dados ao arquivo ao invés de sobrescrevê-lo.

**Com o já descontinuado MySQL:** - conforme pedido no comentário

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","USUARIO","SENHA");

mysql_select_db("nome_DB", $conn);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT nome_coluna FROM nome_tabela");

$k=1;
$i=1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $res = $row["nome_coluna"]."\n";
    file_put_contents("arquivo".$i.".txt", $res, FILE_APPEND);

    if (($k%18000)==0){
        $i=$i+1;
    }

    $k=$k+1;
}
```

Comment: Boa Leo, consegue o mesmo exemplo com MySQL?

Comment: @Marcelo resposta com MySQL também

Answer (score 1):

Depois que pegar o array com as informações do banco de dados, use a função [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) para fazer a divisão desse array por um número arbitrario(nesse exemplo é o dois).

[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) vai formatar cada elemento do array como uma linha no arquivo, pois o separador é `\r\n`.

Para escrver os arquivos em alguma pasta do servidor pode usar [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php). Outra opção é a combinação [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) e [`fclose()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php).

```
$arr = array('url1', 'url2', 'url3', 'url4', 'url5', 'url6');

$arquivos = array_chunk($arr, 2);


$i=1;
foreach ($arquivos as $item) {
    $str = implode("\r\n", $item);
    file_put_contents($i++.'.txt', $str);
}
```

Ao chamar `array_chunk()` `$arquivos` terá essa estrutra.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => url1
            [1] => url2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => url3
            [1] => url4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => url5
            [1] => url6
        )

)
```

Comment: Apenas correção, seria fopen() e não fopne(), certo?

Comment: @TiagoBoeing, correto, corrigi já. Obrigado.